# speed up numpy with multiple GPU's

Tags: python, numpy

I have several variables, and I am trying to do the following:

```
np.array([ yHat[idS == i] for i in outIds])
```

Here, `outIds`, `idS` and `yHat` are relatively large numpy arrays. Is there a way of getting the same result, but faster? I am trying to get the values of `yHat`for the right ids. The order does matter. I have multiple GPU's so a multi-GPU solution would also be great!

Comment: Nvidia CUDA might be relevant https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-python

Comment: `temp  = dict(zip(idS, yHat));np.array([ temp[i] for i in outIds  ])` appears to be much faster! Currently am using this ... Thanks for your help.